# How to correctly add Javascript in functions.php

Tags: php, jquery, woocommerce-offtopic

I would like to remove some ugly looking arrows that are standard on cart buttons in WooCommerce. To achieve this, I found a tip of adding the following code, which should remove the arrows when the document has loaded.

I assume I am going to put it in my functions.php? How exactly would I do that?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".woocommerce-cart").html(function(i, val) {
    return val.replace(" →", "");
    });
    $(".woocommerce-cart").html(function(i, val) {
    return val.replace("← ", "");
    });
});
```

**EDIT**

Okay. I've tried this approach:

Made a file named 'removeArrows.js' and placed it in my plugin folder. This has the same content as the original code, except jQuery instead $. Then I added the following to functions.php:

```
function wpb_adding_scripts() {
      wp_register_script('my_amazing_script', plugins_url('removeArrows.js', FILE), array('jquery'),'1.1', true);
     wp_enqueue_script('my_amazing_script');
 } 

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpb_adding_scripts' );
```

I can't figure out how to make the code display properly. This did not work. Any suggestions to make this work?

[jQuery Snippet Source](http://www.designagogo.co.uk/removing-arrows-from-woocommerce-buttons/)

Comment: That's crazy: can't you edit the arrows out in the code that generates them? (Or is it downloaded from an external source?) In any case you can do both replaces in a single function to avoid reading and writing all the HTML inside the cart block twice. I don't know a way to directly inject that into the page from functions.php but you can save it in a separate script file (if you don't already have one you can add it to) and then [`wp-enqueue-script`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) it. You'll also have to change the `$`s to `jQuery` (see that page section 7)

Comment: Nope, I'm pretty sure it can't be removed before inserted. If it can, I haven't been able to find a way to do it.

Good point about adding it in a single function. Would it look like this?

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".woocommerce-cart").html(function(i, val) {
        return val.replace(" →", "");
        return val.replace("← ", "");
        });
    });

I will look into the enqueue script. Seems a bit complicated, though.. Thanks!

Comment: Okay. I tried this approach;

Made a file named 'removeArrows.js' and placed it in my plugin folder. This has the same content as the original code, except jQuery instead $.

then I added the following to functions.php;

`function wpb_adding_scripts() {
wp_register_script('my_amazing_script', plugins_url('removeArrows.js', __FILE__), array('jquery'),'1.1', true);
wp_enqueue_script('my_amazing_script');
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpb_adding_scripts' );  


(Sorry, I cant figure out how to make the code display properly)

This did not work. Can you help me fix it?

Comment: Please file an [edit] and add all relevant info **directly to your question**  Do not use the comment section to add code

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your `$scr` in your [`wp_register_script()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register_script) function is wrong. Given that your functions.php is inside your plugin, and your removeArrows.js is in the root of your plugin, your `$scr` should look like this

```
plugins_url( '/removeArrows.js' , __FILE__ )
```

Another point of note, it is always good practice to load your scripts and styles last. This will ensure that it will not get overriden by other scripts and styles. To do this, just add a very low priority (very high number) to your priority parameter (`$priority`) of [`add_action`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_action).

```
 add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpb_adding_scripts', 999 );
```

And **always** load/enqueue scripts and styles via the [`wp_enqueue_scripts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_enqueue_scripts) action hook, as this is the proper hook to use. **Do not** load scripts and styles directly to `wp_head` or `wp_footer`

**EDIT**

For themes, as you've indicated that you now moved everything to your theme, your `$scr` would change to this

```
 get_template_directory_uri() . '/removeArrows.js'
```

for parent themes and this

```
get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/removeArrows.js'
```

for child themes. Your complete code should look like this

```
function wpb_adding_scripts() {
    wp_register_script('my_amazing_script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/removeArrows.js', array('jquery'),'1.1', true);
    wp_enqueue_script('my_amazing_script');
} 

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpb_adding_scripts', 999 );
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your great advice. This seems like the approach to use. One question though; the functions.php is in my theme folder. How would I link the js-file if it's just in the same, theme root folder?

Comment: You should keep everything in a plugin or in a theme, don't split them. If you are in a theme, your `$scr` would be `get_template_directory_uri() . '/removeArrows.js'` for parent themes, and `get_templatestylesheet_directory_uri() . '/removeArrows.js'` for childthemes

Comment: Tried again, this time adding the removeArrows.js directly in theme folder and using the following in functions.php;
    function wpb_adding_scripts() {
wp_register_script('my_amazing_script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/removeArrows.js', __FILE__), array('jquery'),'1.1', true);
wp_enqueue_script('my_amazing_script');
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpb_adding_scripts', 999 );

this gives me Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ',' on the wp_register_script line.

Comment: `get_template_directory_uri() . '/removeArrows.js', FILE)` should just be `get_template_directory_uri() . '/removeArrows.js'`

Comment: Nope. Used your completely code you edited into the bottom of your original post. Only thing it does is to freeze the cart page when viewing the contents. I think I'll just give up :-)
One last resort though; you started by mentioning that get_template_directory_uri() is for parent themes, and then in the final complete code that it's for child themes. Which is it? My theme is a parent :-)

Comment: Sorry, made a copy and paste error there. The last piece of complete code is for parent theme. If this doesn't work, you will need to have a look at your script

Answer (score 9):

I would not add another external js file, its just an extra and unnecessary resource to fetch and that is something we want to cut down on in terms of page loading times.

I would add this jQuery snippet in your websites head using the `wp_head` hook. You would paste the following in your theme or plugins functions file. I have also made sure jQuery is in no-conflict mode as you can see below.

```
add_action('wp_head','woocommerce_js');

    function woocommerce_js()
    { // break out of php ?>

  <script>

    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $(".woocommerce-cart").html(function(i, val) {
        return val.replace(" →", "");
        });
        $(".woocommerce-cart").html(function(i, val) {
        return val.replace("← ", "");
        });
    });

    </script>

    <?php } // break back into php
```

Once you have done this and refreshed your page, check the page source to make sure this jQuery snippet is in fact being loaded into your page. If it is then it should work unless their is something off in the actual jQuery snippet you are using.

Comment: That's not the WordPress way to load Javascript, though. See [`wp_enqueue_script()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) for more information.

Comment: Hi @PatJ, I agree, for loading an external JS library or JS file with all your Javascript functions in it, then yes absolutely that would be the correct way. However if you are loading a snippet of Javascript it does not make sense to create a whole new JS file and add an additional HTTP request just for that. Take Google Analytics for example, in 99% of themes or custom builds, the JS will be added into the the header or footer via theme options or functions file. Its common practice to include JS or even CSS snippets this way.

Comment: "Common practice" doesn't make it correct, though. The [`wp_enqueue_script()` docs](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) even state **This is the recommended method of linking JavaScript to a WordPress generated page**.

Comment: If you take WordPress default twentyfourteen theme, it loads html5.js in the header.php. Granted its doe this way for a reason so as to check of the browser meets the condition of being IE < 9, but my point is that understandably, enqueuing is the recommended and preferred method but depending on all the other variables/circumstances surrounding what you are trying to achieve it may not always be the most practical and I think some discretion should be used. Look, I could be completely wrong in this view as well, I'm interested to hear what some of the really experienced guys have to say :-)

Comment: Thanks for your great suggestion. I can't get it to work though; if I add your code inside the <?php tag of my functions.php I get a 'Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in /somepath.../functions.php on line 1146'. If I add it outside the <?php, it simply seems to echo the given code in top of the page. What am I missing here?

Comment: When you paste it in your functions.php file - remove the first `<?php` from the code I supplied as you already have the `<?php` opening tag on line 1 of your functions.php file. I have edited my original answer and removed it from there as well.

Comment: This JS code needs to wrapped in <script></script> . This method to render JS in WP is not recommended, but in some cases quick solutions are more important than best practices.

Answer (score 4):

As the answer is accepted already so, I just want to say there's another way to enqueue javascript code in footer which I have done many times.

in functions.php file:

```
function load_script_to_remove_arrow(){
?>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".woocommerce-cart").html(function(i, val) {
    return val.replace(" →", "");
    });
    $(".woocommerce-cart").html(function(i, val) {
    return val.replace("← ", "");
    });
});
</script>
<?php
}
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'load_script_to_remove_arrow' );
```

you can load this script to particular page template only by using condition

```
if( is_page_template( 'page-template.php' ) ):

//put above code (or just add_action part) inside this condition to load file only if the condition is true 

endif;
```

if the page-template.php is in directory ( say templates directory in your theme's root dir ) you can write like:

```
is_page_template( 'templates/page-template.php' );
```

Comment: I would not recommend "baking" the JavaScript into the footer like this. It prevents it from being unhookable or modifiable (at least, easily) which is extremely important in plugin and theme development. If you're the end-user of a site and need a quick script or something, go for it - but even still `wp_enqueue_script()` is almost always universally better and more flexible.

Answer (score -1):

To answer the question we must first make a distinction between javascript and JQuery.

To state it in a simple fashion:

- Javascript is based on ECMAScript
- JQuery is a library for Javascript

So in reality you ask two different questions:

- Your title speaks about a solution for implementing javascript
- Your question speaks about a solution for implementing JQuery

Because the Google results show your title and all the content of the page talks about JQuery this can become very frustrating to people that search for a javascript solution.

And now for the JQuery solution:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'script-id', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/script.js', array ( 'jquery' ), 1.1, true);
```

And the javascript solution:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'script-id', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/script.js', array(), '1.0.0', true );
```

This code can be added to your functions.php
The location of the scripts in both cases is `wp-content/themes/theme-name/js/script.js`

Happy coding!

Comment: Around the time when OP posted, devs did use jquery and javascript interchangeably. It's not at all accurate, but it was how popular jquery was and how much javascript was missing features.